# How to add only new entries from a constantly updating API to a database

Tags: python, database, api

Coding (python) newbie here.I am trying to make a small project where I gather news headlines from an API.The API I am trying to use is [newsapi.org](https://newsapi.org). Every time I enquire the API, It gives me a a long list of news articles,which I add to a database . But when I enquire again after some time gap , I get a new article(S) plus many, if not all the previous articles. How do I avoid adding duplicates to the database? I thought of iterating through the last few new entries and see if such articles already exist but somehow I feel that is not the way.Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The API you want to use includes a `from` parameter that you can set to filter the articles returned and only get the ones that are more recent.

If you store the current time each time you gather data from the api, you can use it in the `from` parameter on the next api call you will do to only get what has been published in between the two calls.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but all I could find about `from` is the one from the import module

Comment: Look at the `from` parameter in this page and at the example request on the right:
https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything

Comment: Oh wow.Thank you. I should learn to read docs in depth I suppose.But how do I do it in other APIs? for curiosity sake

Comment: You're welcome. For other APIs.... well that's the fun part. As everyone can implement the functions they want as will without any obligation to follow a specific standard you'll have to study each API individually and write specific code for each of them.  Enjoy!